# Dúvida query oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

Boa tarde,
gostaria de criar "Ciclos"(campo Ciclo, numeração sequencial crescente), aonde o início do ciclo sera sempre no "Cod = 10 (campo cod)" e o Fim do ciclo o "Cod 99 (campo Cod)". No caso do Fim do Ciclo se for "Cod = 99" (em vermelho) considerar um Fim único. A coluna "Acumulado Tempo", devera conter a somatória de cada Ciclo.

Desde ja agradeço atenção e colaboração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ficou pouco claro , ao menos para mim , a coluna ciclo já existe ? Seria só uma visão em um select ? Todavia pesquise por SEQUENCE CICLE.

Comment: Boa tarde,  a coluna Ciclo,  não existe. Necessito exibir no momento do SELECT.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23sql-1906475.html , tente um "running total"